# How to go to menu page after log in validation?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm now only few days with Xamarin Forms and trying to do this in MVVM architecture. How can I load the next page (Home/Menu Page) after this if else statements? Is this way I have done this correct?
My instructions were that there should be email validation, and the password cannot be less than 6 characters.

```
    public User User 
    {
      get { return user; }
      set { user = value; }
    }

    public Command LoginCommand 
    {
      get 
      {
        return new Command(() => 
        {
          bool usr = string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Username);
          bool pass = string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Password);

          if (usr && pass) 
          {
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Please enter Credentials", "OK");
          } 
          else 
          {
            if (EmailRegex.IsMatch(User.Username)) 
            {
              if (pass) 
              {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Please enter password!", "OK");
              } 
              else if (User.Password.Length < 6) 
              {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Password must be at least 6 characters", "OK");
              } 
              else 
              {
                //load menu page
              }
            } 
            else 
            {
              App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Email is not a valid email address!", "OK");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    Regex EmailRegex = new Regex(@ "^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");

    public bool ValidateEmail(string email) 
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        return false;

      return EmailRegex.IsMatch(email);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage ());

Comment: You should be using [behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/) for validation purpose, I can guide you further if you are interested

Comment: @G.hakim I could finally navigate to the next page by adding only 
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());,
But I was also told to disable the button until passing those validations using behaviors. I would be very thankful if you could guide me.

Comment: What are the validations that you need can you describe them?

Comment: @G.hakim the login button should only be enabled after checking the email validation and password length(at least 6 characters)

Comment: For Email check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xg9gY6VUBAs

Comment: @G.hakim Thank you for the link. I did that. But still I couldnt found how to add a behavior for a button. Can you guide me further?

Comment: Behavior for a button?

Comment: @G.hakim I mean I want to disable the button until user enters a valid email and a valid password (valid password=more than 8 characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for Navigation in `MVVM` :

```
public INavigation Navigation { get; set;}


    public YourViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        this.YourButtonClick= new Command(async () => await GotoPage2());
    }


    public async Task GotoPage2()
    {
         /////
         await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set MainPage as a Navigation Page in App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
```

then use

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
```